# solve the vector equation for a and b

Tags: vectors

> Solve the vector equation for a and b:
>   ${\begin{bmatrix}2\\b\\3\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}a\\5\\4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}b\\2a\\7\end{bmatrix}}$

I don't understand the question.  I am aware of simultaneous equations with the determinant for matrices but this does not seem applicable to this question.

Answer (score 5):

It just means this -

$2+a=b$ and $b+5=2a$

$a=7$ and $b=9$

Comment: I am sorry if this is an inappropriate question but what was your JEE rank? I'm an aspired.

Comment: @N.S.JOHN You could have asked in chat. Anyway, It's AIR151 in 2012.

Comment: Did you go to coaching classes?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN No, I didn't. I solved lot of papers from FITJEE etc..

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{cases}
2+a=b\\
b+5=2a\\
3+4=7
\end{cases}$$

From the first line: $a=\color{red}{b-2}$ Now $b+5=2\color{red}{(b-2)}$

So $b+5=2b-4\Longrightarrow \boxed{b=9}$ And $\boxed{a=7}$

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can formulate your equations in matrix form and apply your known solution methods:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2\\b\\3\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}a\\5\\4\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}b\\2a\\7\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 1 \\
2 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\
b \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The third equation features no unkown and it is true, so it can be neglected. If it were false the system had no solution.